# Assembly, detecting overflow register

Tags: assembly, x86, overflow, integer-overflow

I have this very simple assembly code:

```
start:
add ax, 100    
; if ax overflow add to bx 1
jmp start
```

but i don't know how to detect ax register overflow, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ADD` instruction sets appropriate `FLAGS` reflecting the overflow condition. There are two kinds of overflow: signed and unsigned. You have to decide what's appropriate and use `jc/jnc` for unsigned and `jo/jno` for signed.

```
add ax, 100
jnc noUnsignedOverflow
...
noUnsignedOverflow:

add ax, 100
jno noSignedOverflow
...
noSignedOverflow:
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `jo` (jump if overflow) or `jno` (jump  if no overflow)

Check out the [Intel x86 JUMP quick reference](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html)